# Select MAX field without repeating another

Tags: php, sql

sorry for my english, i use google translator...

I have a table like this:

```
  id | name | number  
----------------------

- 1  |   John   | 110
- 2  |   Carl   | 95
- 3  |   Carl   |  213
- 4  |   Jesus  |  4
- 5  |   John   |  112
- 6  |   Jesus  |  87
- 7  |   Carl   |  9
```

And i want to get something like this..

```
id    | name   | number
----------------------

- 3   |  Carl  | 213
- 5   |  John  | 112
- 6   |  Jesus | 87
```

Can anyone help me??

Thanks

Comment: `select max(id), name, max(number) from ... group by name`?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify what database you are using but, you can use a subquery to return the `max(number)` for each `name` and then join that back to your table to get the final result:

```
select
  t1.id,
  t1.name,
  t1.number
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select max(number) number, name
  from yourtable
  group by name
) m
  on t1.name = m.name
  and t1.number = m.number;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccbbe/1).  This will return the `id` that is associated with the `max(number)`.  If your database supports windowing functions, then you could use `row_number()`:

```
select id, name, number
from 
(
  select id, name, number,
    row_number() over(partition by name
                      order by number desc) seq
  from yourtable
) m
where seq = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fdd92/2)